# How to Change window.setInterval(function(){ value from textbox and submit button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

i Have a small script that need to change `window.setInterval(function(){` value `}, 1000);` from text box and button.

i tried this code that is working, if i change `rrrr` id value from HTML code then its working,  but not working from changing text box value after HTML render.

i need to change this value from text box and submit button.

My Try is :

```js
var delay = document.getElementById("rrrr").value;
window.setInterval(function(){
$( "#button-next" ).click();
}, delay);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="rrrr" value="1000" style="width:50">
<button id="rrrr">submit</button>
```

any suggestion so i should change ?

Comment: As i understand you want to set value of input to delay of `setinterval` and in interval fire click event, is it right? Also what is `rrrr` button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what your want ? With this schema, you could change time interval as you want, by changing the text input and clicking on [submit] button.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var iHandle = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
    //
    // read initial value:
    //
    var delay = document.getElementById("rrrr").value;
    //
    // set initial interval:
    //
    iHandle = window.setInterval(function() {
       // console.log(delay);
        $("#button-next" ).click();
    }, delay);
    //
    // change delay by user trigger (pressing on button):
    //
    $("#rrrrbutton").on("click", function () {
        //
        // clear previous setInterval() object if existent:
        //
        if(iHandle) {
          clearInterval(iHandle);           
        }
        //
        // read new value:
        //
        var delay = document.getElementById("rrrr").value;
        //
        // set new interval:
        //
        iHandle = window.setInterval(function() {
          console.log(delay);
          $("#button-next" ).click();
        }, delay);
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="rrrr" value="1000" style="width:50">
<button id="rrrrbutton">submit</button>

</body>
</html>
```

The console.log() is only here for debugging:

```
console.log(delay);
```

---

As we see some common code, we can abbreviate the programming, by defining a public user function runInterval():

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var iHandle = 0;

function runInterval() {
    //
    // clear previous setInterval() object if existent:
    //
    if(iHandle) {
      clearInterval(iHandle);           
    }
    //
    // read new value:
    //
    var delay = document.getElementById("rrrr").value;
    //
    // set new interval:
    //
    iHandle = window.setInterval(function() {
      console.log(delay);
      $("#button-next" ).click();
    }, delay);
    //
    return true;
}
//
// do this job after page loading:
//    
$(document).ready(function() {
  //
  // do initial interval:
  //
  runInterval();
  
  //
  // change delay by user trigger (pressing on button):
  //
  $("#rrrrbutton").on("click", function () {
     //
     // relaunch setInterval() by reading new interval value:
     //
     return runInterval();
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="rrrr" value="1000" style="width:50">
<button id="rrrrbutton">submit</button>

  ......

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ya it is almost Right, that i want, But here i want first time the window.setInterval(function() {      ------with ------- 1000);  value should work without button click, Means default value should be work without click, and then it is right that you worked that is it should be change with textbox value and button click

Comment: Many thanks. I've added code to to initial .setInterval().

Answer (score 1):

The type of your input value is string when setInterval function expects number so you may want to try changing `type="text"` to `type="number"` or try changing the type in assignment:

```
var delay = Number(document.getElementById("rrrr").value);
```

or in the function itself:

```
window.setInterval(function(){
$( "#button-next" ).click();
}, Number(delay));
```